# Layover in Toronto, do I need a transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, filipino-citizens, toronto

I an a Filipino. I will be travelling from Lima, Peru to Malaysia. I have a 2-hour layover in Toronto YYZ, then to Shanghai. Do I need a transit visa? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Philippine passport holders can [transit without visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/eligibility.html) through certain Canadian airports, but only when transiting to or from the US, with a US visa.

Since you are not going to or from the US, that doesn't apply to you, and you need a Canadian visa as Philippine passport holders normally need to enter Canada.